# How to set start day of the week as Monday in kendo-datepicker for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, datepicker, telerik, kendo-datetimepicker

I need to use kendo in my Angular project. But the requirement is once the date selection popup is open, starting day of the week should be Monday instead of Sunday which is the default behavior.

**Current behavior:**

[image]

```
<kendo-datepicker
    calendarType="classic"
    [animateCalendarNavigation]="true"
    [value]="value"
>
```

I searched a lot to find a setting like **firstDayOfWeek='Monday'** this, but unable to find anywhere.

If anyone know about it please share your thoughts.

Reference: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this Telerik [thread](https://www.telerik.com/forums/firstday-of-week-for-kendo-ui-datepicker-for-angular). Has to do with updating the datepicker's culture. "The first day of the week is controlled by the chosen LOCALE_ID. For instance, if the locale is set up to 'en-GB', then the component will display the week from Monday."

Comment: But this will apply to all datepickers in the module, right?
I only need this particular datepicker to start with Monday, in all other areas it should start by default on Sunday.

Comment: @aks44 - Yes, that's true. Unfortunately, Telerik doesn't provide us with a property to override the culture of the specific component.

Answer (score 0):

Write a service that should overwrite the calendar intl service `CldrIntlService`. Create a service file `first-day-intl.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CldrIntlService } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';

@Injectable()
export class FirstDayIntlService extends CldrIntlService {
    public firstDay(): number {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

In the `@NgModule` add the created service to the `providers` section.

```
providers: [
        {
            provide: IntlService,
            useClass: FirstDayIntlService,
        },
    ],
```

This will change the calender start day of the week.